# Logic for reconstruction of json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hope you are doing well.

```
 [ {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
      "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
    },
  ]
```

Considering there are multiple objects for each userId and I want to group them together in the below format.

```
const json2 =  {
     1: [{},{},{}],
     2:[{},{},{}],
     3:[{},{},{}],    
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please read the tag description before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals. Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_ Your JSON data isn't valid.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform, not a code writing service. Do you have a question? [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: be more specific about how your expected result should look like and what have you tried?

Comment: you are very welcome, have a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the reduce function, but next time please provide what you tried before asking.

```js
const input = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.userId]??=[];
  acc[el.userId].push(el);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```

Comment: this output doesn't look at all like what OP wanted

Comment: @ChrisG yes it does, it groups the elements using userId

Comment: looks more like he wants an object for every property, per userId